# Replace character in odd index with '+'

Tags: python

I want to change character in odd position with `+` in string of n `-`

```
def make_sep_line(n):
    result = '-'*n*2
    
for i in range(1,n*2):
    if i%2!=0 :
        result=result[0:i]+'+'+result[i+1:]
        
        return result
```

Comment: Why not just use `result = '-+'*n`?

Comment: `results[1::2]` is the odd positions. You can give `results[1::2] = '+'`

Comment: I have to use for and if like if n =4 the result should be -+-+-+-

Comment: @joe that wouldn't work. Maybe `results[1::2] = ['+']*n`

Comment: Dang. Yea. Thats correct

Comment: `def make_sep_line(n):
    result = '-'*n*2
    result[1::2] = ['+']*n
    return result` TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment

Comment: Or `return ''.join('+' if i%2 else c for i, c in enumerate('-'*n*2))`

Comment: For `n=4`, what is your desired output?  In your comment, you suggest that it is `-+-+-+-`, but your code and the code in the comments all seem to result in strings with an even number of characters.

Comment: I want the result of -+-+-+- like that I'm a biginner and very confused

Comment: I want a string with n character of '-' seprate wit n-1 character '+' @CryptoFool

Comment: @saadoummiss - gotcha, per my answer.  I'd suggest that you improve your question by editing it and moving this last comment into it to make it clearer to readers what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code outside of indentation.  Here's your code with proper indentation along with a call to your function for which the result is then printed:

```
def make_sep_line(n):
    result = '-' * n * 2
    for i in range(1, n * 2):
        if i % 2 != 0:
            result = result[0:i] + '+' + result[i + 1:]
    return result

print(make_sep_line(4))
```

Result:

```
-+-+-+-+
```

If what you want is what you say in your comment, then you want to slightly modify the solution, as follows:

```
def make_sep_line(n):
    result = '-' * (n * 2 - 1)
    for i in range(1, n * 2 - 1):
        if i % 2 != 0:
            result = result[0:i] + '+' + result[i + 1:]
    return result

print(make_sep_line(4))
```

Result;

```
-+-+-+-
```

I'm not sure what the constraints on your solution are exactly. There are many ways to approach this problem. The concise way I'd produce these same strings is as follows:

```
n = 4
print('-+' * n)
print('-+' * (n-1) + '-')
```

Result:

```
-+-+-+-+
-+-+-+-
```